# TSQL Search Box First Name Surname order priority

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a front end search box where the user can search for someone by firstname, middlename, surname or job title and bulk of the backend code looks like this:

```
SELECT TOP 50 * FROM (SELECT [EmployeeId], SUM(MatchOrder) as MatchOrder
            FROM (SELECT
                    [EmployeeId], 
                    CASE WHEN A.[EmployeeFieldId] = 4 Then 15 --Surname
                         WHEN A.[EmployeeFieldId] in (1, 2) Then 15 --PreferredName, FirstName
                         WHEN A.[EmployeeFieldId] = 3 Then 5 --MiddleName
                         WHEN A.[EmployeeFieldId] = 5 Then 20 --JobTitle
                         ELSE 3 
                    END as MatchOrder
                  FROM [latest].[EmployeeAttributes] A
                  WHERE (' + @search + ')
                  ) internal
            GROUP BY EmployeeId) A
join dbo.vwEmployees E on E.EmployeeId = A.EmployeeId -- TEMP
            ORDER BY 2 DESC'
```

Each employeeID is given a  score (MatchOrder) which is totalled depending on how many of the above criteria are met (e.g. First Name + Surname match = 30) and then the search is ordered by the MatchOrder score to be displayed by the front end,  But the problem is that if someone's First and Surname are very similar, e.g. Patrick Patterson and I only search for Pat Rice, then Patrick Patterson (30 pts) appears above Patrick Rice(30pts) because the First Name is being matched twice.

I'd like for it to either lower the points score if the match is doubly made, or modify my switch statement to somehow do this (nested case?

Do you know how I can combat this? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since [EmployeeFieldId] is always mapped to the same [MatchOrder], you should be able to control this by including [EmployeeFieldId] in the "internal" result set and slapping a DISTINCT clause on the SELECT:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT
        [EmployeeId],
        [EmployeeFieldId],
        CASE WHEN A.[EmployeeFieldId] = 4 Then 15 --Surname
                WHEN A.[EmployeeFieldId] in (1, 2) Then 15 --PreferredName, FirstName
                WHEN A.[EmployeeFieldId] = 3 Then 5 --MiddleName
                WHEN A.[EmployeeFieldId] = 5 Then 20 --JobTitle
                ELSE 3 
        END as MatchOrder
    FROM [latest].[EmployeeAttributes] A
    WHERE (' + @search + ')
```

That way, each employee will get at max one of the same field IDs applied towards their score.

Comment: Hey @duney - did this work for you?  Let me know if it didn't give you what you want and a little more detail about the requirements and I can help.